# Express endpoints timing out

Tags: node.js, express, timeout

I'm trying to get a small API going on with my app. I'd like to be able to validate a certificate, which is already working on localhost like so:

`localhost:3000/verify/asd` -> will look for any certificate with the id "asd" and return it or an object containing the error code.

But when deploying this to heroku with the procfile as so:
`web: node igdaapi.js` will just timeout whenever I try to do `domain:PORT/verify/asd`

I'm trying to run this on a wordpress page with the raw html thing. The html i'm trying to use works fine when trying everything in local, but when uploading it to wordpress and then deploying this in heroku it just won't work.

This is the code:

````
const { find_certificate_in_db, generate_certificate_pdf } = require('./igdabot_general/general_certif_commands');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"))

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Our app is running on port ${ PORT }`);
});

app.get('/verify/:id', async function (req, res) {
    let cert_id = req.params.id;
    console.log("Hello, we need to verify", cert_id);
    certObject = await find_certificate_in_db(cert_id);

    console.log("Certification object: ");

    res.send(certObject);
});```
````

Comment: with heroku I don't think you need to pass a port. They gave you the domain right? just navigate `domain/verify/asd`